# actionbarsherlock sherlockfragment google maps v2 is null

Tags: actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use Actionbarsherlock with a tab bar and in one of those taps i want a map.
I have successfully created an map in a sherlockfragment with google map v2, but I want add markers programmatically to the map.

```
public class Map_fragment extends SherlockFragment {
static final LatLng Cph = new LatLng(55.702355,12.436523);
private final static String MAP_TAG = "map";
private GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
    SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment) (getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAP_TAG));
    if(map==null){
        Log.d("MAP", "NULL");
        }
    if(map!=null){
    Log.d("MAP", "   " + map);
    Log.d("GETMAP", " " + map.getMap());
    }


    //GoogleMap mMap = map.getMap();
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Cph, 14));
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapv2_layout, container, false);


}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
public void setupMap(){
    Log.d("SUCCESS" , "SUCCESS");
}
}
```

I have tried with many different suggestions from other sites and posts on stack overflow, but the map is always null.

I have tried with onCreate and onAttach after suggestions from others, but with no luck.

I have tried for a long time and Im about to pull my hair out :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually adding the SherlockMapFragment class to the ActionBarSherlock library, found here http://code.google.com/p/opendatakit/source/browse/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockMapFragment.java?spec=svn.tables.35872cc920b5668de433c6fc81efc86c4970bac1&repo=tables&r=0c1b0212e5b8bb5af8ce2b8e9357cd30e3870084

Then with the following lines i finally got "gMap" that wasn't null

```
SupportMapFragment map;
    map = (SupportMapFragment) (getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    gMap = map.getMap();
```